# How do you link a C file with a nasm file?

Tags: c, macos, assembly, nasm

C File that I am trying to link with my NASM file

```
  /*
   *  filename:  maxofthreetest.c
   *
   *  to compile/link: gcc maxofthreetest.c maxofthree.o -o maxofthreetest
   *  to run:  ./maxofthreetest
   */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

   int64_t maxofthree( int64_t, int64_t, int64_t );

   int main() {
      printf( "%lld\n", maxofthree(  1, -4, -7 ) );
      printf( "%lld\n", maxofthree(  2, -6,  1 ) );
      printf( "%lld\n", maxofthree(  2,  3,  1 ) );
      printf( "%lld\n", maxofthree( -2,  4,  3 ) );
      printf( "%lld\n", maxofthree(  2, -6,  5 ) );
      printf( "%lld\n", maxofthree(  2,  4,  6 ) );
      return 0;
   }
```

Nasm file

```
               ;to assemble:   nasm -f macho64 maxofthree.nasm

               global  maxofthree
               section .text
 maxofthree: mov     rax, rdi     ; result (rax) initially holds x
               cmp     rax, rsi     ; is x less than y?
               cmovl   rax, rsi     ; if yes, set result to y
               cmp     rax, rdx     ; is max(x,y) less than z?
               cmovl   rax, rdx     ; if yes, set result to z
               ret                  ; return what's in rax
```

I have been getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_maxofthree", referenced from:
      _main in maxofthreetest-f1d20a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: This does not look like C++ code, and judging by the error, was not compiled as C++.

Comment: You link object files. Some are produced by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), others are produced by `nasm`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That's what `gcc maxofthreetest.c maxofthree.o -o maxofthreetest` does: the `.o` from NASM, the other .o from an internal temporary from compiling the `.c`.  The problem is the lack of a leading `_` in the asm symbol name; this example would work on Linux.

Comment: IDK if there's a better duplicate that's more specifically about leading underscores on MacOS.  The one I chose was the first that seemed good enough.